# Multi-dimensional MVT problem

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be differentiable, with $f(0) = f(1)$  and $f'(0) = f'(1)$. Why is it true that for any $v$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ there is an x such that the inner product of $f'(x)$ with $v$ is $0$? I feel like I need to use the multidimensional mean value theorem here, but I can't tell how it would tell me anything about dot products.

Comment: Saying $f(0) = f(1)$ makes no sense because the domain of $f$ is $\Bbb{R}^n$, so $f$ has to "eat" an $n$-tuple of real numbers.

Comment: Whoops, edited.

Comment: I don't think this argument is true.

Answer (score 0):

Define $g_v(t)=\langle f(t),v\rangle,$ where $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is a unit vector (if $v=0$, then what you ask holds, so assume the vector is nonzero). Clearly $g_v(t)=0$ if and only if $g_{cv}(t)=0$ for all $c\neq 0.$

Now $g_v:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable since $f$ is differentiable. Moreover, $g_v(0)=g_v(1)$ and $g_v'(0)=g_v'(1).$ Can you finish from here?

Comment: Is $\langle f'(t), v \rangle = g_v'(t)$? I see that MVT gives $g_v(1) - g_v(0) = 0 = g_v'(c)$ for some c in $[0, 1]$. Is that all I need?

Comment: Yes. By definition, the derivative of $g_v$ turns out to be exactly that.